# A telegram bot to get things from db

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to make a bot that works like:

```
/whatis python
if Response=="cat":
    Reply python is something someething
else:
    reply something something
```

But how do i get user response? I use

```
content = update.effective_message
if content == "cat":
    Something something
else:
something something
```

But this one doesn't work, so i make another one:

```
content = update.effective_message.text.split(None, 1)
if content == "cat":
     Cat is Something something
else:
    what is that
```

This one works, but even if the respond is "cat" it respond with "what is that". Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`"cat"` is a string. `update.effective_message` is an instance of `telegram.Message`. `update.effective_message.text.split(None, 1)` is a list of strings. Comparing an instance of `telegram.Message`or a list to to string for equality will always give `False`.